# How do i access JSON data to send to Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I make a call to an API and get a JSON response. For the better half of 2 days i have been trying to access the data, and send it to a CSV file, or push it to Pandas with no luck. I have gone through page after page of assistance, but something is just not clicking.

Below is the JSON data, all i need are the following elements **singleLineAddress**, **isAgentsAdvice** & **contractDate**

```
[
  {
    "_embedded":{
      "propertySummaryList":[
        {
          "propertySummary":{
            "address":{
              "singleLineAddress":"Example St"
            },
            "id":47328284,
            "lastSaleDetail":{
              "contractDate":"Example",
              "isAgentsAdvice":Yes,
              "isArmsLength":0,
              "isPriceWithheld":0,
```

The ideal end result would be a csv export that had the following column names

**Address** | **AA** | **Contract_Date**

So far i've tried to create a simple dataframe in python, however it seems to always print on singular lines, so i moved over to attempting to 'flatten' the file for easier processing, but no data was extracted at all in those attempts.

I attempted to follow a few github recipes, but the overall theme seemed to be just flattening the data, which as above didnt seem to work well with my json file.

I attempted the normal dataframe route but didnt have much luck, my main focus has been in both json_normalize, and flatten_json type work, but if someone wants to offer a better solution, i am all ears.

Any help is appreciated. I'd appreciate any leads on what may be 'missing' from my knowledge base around JSON and Pandas as it's been quite handy the last few weeks.

Cheers

Comment: Can you help with the sample complete json and you don't need pandas to over complicate the things. I have done the same thing in past using API response.

Comment: I can't post the whole JSON, as it says it's too long.....but the above response basically repeats, and is the only part i'm interested in getting.